# mySQL JOIN syntax using bridging table

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to export some data from two tables bridged by a third table that stores the one (file) to many (keywords) relationship.

Tables are like so:

```
files
id, url, title

keywords
id, word

bridge
file, word
```

What I want is to produce an export that has one row per file like this:

```
files.id, files.url, files.title, keyword1|keyword2|keyword3|...
```

Any advice greatly appreciated!

Comment: If it is _really_ a one-to-many relationship, you don't need an extra table, you only really need a foreign key. However, judging from your explanation, it seems that what you have is, in fact, a many-to-many relationship (in that case, an extra table is needed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to combine the keywords in a `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT 
  files.id, files.url, files.title,
  GROUP_CONCAT(keywords.word ORDER BY keywords.word SEPARATOR '|') keywords
FROM
  files
  LEFT OUTER JOIN bridge ON bridge.file = files.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN keywords ON keywords.id = bridge.word
GROUP BY
  files.id, files.url, files.title
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply Phil! That solved it and gave me some new things to study/play with!  I really need to get an education in SQL more than just learning it as problems arise.  I taught myself perl and PHP but SQL is coming more slowly to me.  Any recommendations for learning it in a comprehensive and organized way?